# How to initialize an object from another object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I've been programming for 15 years, but I'm new to C# and inexperienced with strongly typed languages in general, so I apologize if this is a super-noob question.

I'm trying to avoid a fair amount of repetitive code and am having trouble figuring out a way to do what I want. Here's an example of what I currently have:

```cs
class BaseModel {
    string sharedProperty1;
    string sharedProperty2;
    string sharedProperty3;
    string sharedProperty4;
    string sharedProperty5;
    string sharedProperty6;
}

class ExtendedModelA : BaseModel {
    string exclusivePropertyA;
}

class ExtendedModelB : BaseModel {
    string exclusivePropertyB;
}

// --------

dynamic finalModel;
if( conditionA )
{
    finalModel = new ExtendedModelA{
        sharedProperty1 = 1,
        sharedProperty2 = 2,
        sharedProperty3 = 3,
        sharedProperty4 = 4,
        sharedProperty5 = 5,
        sharedProperty6 = 6,
        exclusivePropertyA = "foo"
    };
}
else
{
    finalModel = new ExtendedModelB{
        sharedProperty1 = 1,
        sharedProperty2 = 2,
        sharedProperty3 = 3,
        sharedProperty4 = 4,
        sharedProperty5 = 5,
        sharedProperty6 = 6,
        exclusivePropertyB = "bar"
    };
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of redundancy since the only difference in initialized values is the last `exclusiveProperty` on each (in my specific case, I have about 30 properties being duplicated in each half of the `if/else` and only 2 or 3 unique). What I'd like to do is initialize a "template" model just once with all the `sharedProperty` values, and inside the `if/else` only need to initialize the `exclusiveProperty` values.

Here's some psuedo-code to illustrate the concept of what I'd like to do, but I haven't been able to make it work, yet.

```cs
var template = new BaseModel
{
    sharedProperty1 = 1,
    sharedProperty2 = 2,
    sharedProperty3 = 3,
    sharedProperty4 = 4,
    sharedProperty5 = 5,
    sharedProperty6 = 6
};

dynamic finalModel;
if( conditionA )
{
    finalModel = new ExtendedModelA{template};
    finalModel.exclusivePropertyA = "foo";
}
else
{
    finalModel = new ExtendedModelB{template};
    finalModel.exclusivePropertyB = "foo";
}
```

I'm familiar with the factory pattern that could be used to accept the "template" and an "extension" as arguments, but that would be just as much code as simply keeping my duplications, so I'm looking for a more... direct? way to do this.

Comment: There isn't a way to do that in C# without a tool like AutoMapper. You should also try to avoid using `dynamic` if you can use a strong type, like `BaseModel`.

Comment: What exactly are you modelling here? Are these classes just dumb data objects, or do they contain logic? Do you  need encapsulation or could you just skip the constructor params and init via public property setters?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. Couldn't you simply reorder the code to instantiate the proper subtype, then assign the shared properties efter the conditional?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way you could do this without repeating code would be to create your object in the if else block with the unique properties, then at the end assign all the shared ones.  This would prevent you from having to repeat code.

```
BaseModel finalModel = null;
if (conditionA)
{
    finalModel = new ExtendedModelA()
                     {
                         exclusivePropertyA = "some value";
                     };
}
else
{
    finalModel = new ExtendedModelB()
                     {
                         exclusivePropertyB = "some other value";
                     };
}
finalModel.sharedProperty1 = "asdf";
// assign the rest of the values
```

You could also have a constructor for the base model that takes a base model as a parameter and assigns all the values to the new object.  This would basically be using the original as a template to create the new.  Then you could create the extended classes with the template and pass it to the base constructor.

```
    class BaseModel
    {
        public string sharedProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string sharedProperty2 { get; set; }
        public string sharedProperty3 { get; set; }
        public string sharedProperty4 { get; set; }
        public string sharedProperty5 { get; set; }
        public string sharedProperty6 { get; set; }

        public BaseModel(BaseModel t)
        {
            //assign template properties 
        }

        public BaseModel()
        {

        }
    }


    class ExtendedModelA : BaseModel
    {
        public string exclusivePropertyA { get; set; }

        public ExtendedModelA(BaseModel t)
            : base(t)
        {

        }
    }

    class ExtendedModelB : BaseModel
    {
        public string exclusivePropertyB { get; set; }

        public ExtendedModelB(BaseModel t)
            : base(t)
        {

        }
    }
```

Then to use it would be

```
BaseModel template = new BaseModel()
                         {
                             //assign values
                         };

ExtendedModelA = new ExtendedModelA(template)
                     {
                         exlusivePropertyA = "asdf";
                     };
```

Comment: Also close, `BaseModel` in your classes doesn't have a constructor that takes zero parameters, so the bottom part of your code would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your second try is almost right. You just need to add a `BaseModel` ctor to `ExtendedModelA` & `ExtendedModelB`:

```
class ExtendedModelA : BaseModel
{
    public ExtendedModelA(BaseModel b)
        : base(b)
    {
    }
}
```

then call it like this:

```
BaseModel template = new BaseModel
{
    // init code
};

finalModel = new ExtendedModelA(template); // note the parenthesis's not curly braces
```

Comment: There is a little more to it, you need to add a constructor to the base model that takes a base model.

Comment: @RonBeyer Of course, that is assumed... He gave partial code, I give partial code. I'm assuming he's got that covered.